# How to store strings alphabetically in a hash table using separate chaining?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm looking for ideas on how to store strings in a hash table using separate chaining. I am creating a puzzle solver that inputs a dictionary of words. Ultimately, I will be trying to reduce the number of times I am searching a puzzle solver method.

If I searched for the string "example" and it was not found then I would automatically know that I wouldn't have to search for the string "examples."

Comment: Store them in the hash table and keep a separate chained list.  Or make your list entries compare based on the key value they contain so that you can insert the list entries into the hash table.  But the hash table won't help you sort.

Comment: Hash table and ordering are mutually exclusive.

Comment: A more efficient approach would be to use a sorted list and a binary search, or, if you want to be able to dynamically update the table, a trie as @LuiggiMendoza suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do sorting with a Hashtable, I would suggest using [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead.